# How to parse parameters from REST style url, ex: /resourses/:id/

Tags: javascript, rest, url

Without help of extra library, is there any simple way to parse parameters from REST style url?
I'm not asking query parameters which behind the `?`
I'm asking for the parameters inside the url, for some examples,

```
https://domain.name/resources/:id
https://domain.name/resources/:id/another_resource/:another_id
```

I want to get the `:id` and `:another_id`
Why do I need this? 
If there is an e-commerce system, an user needs to check his/her order, it's really intuitively he/she can access from the url `https://ecommerce.com/users/:user_id/orders/:order_id`

I know if I'm doing with modern JS framework it can be easily done by some `routing` library, like in `Vue.js` which has `vue-router`
But what I'm making is a really small project, maybe it's just a html with a js file.

Is there any simple way or algorithm to parse the parameters by vanilla javascript?

Comment: You might be able to use a regex, if you know enough about the URL. Something like: `/\/users\/(.*)\/orders\/(.*)/.exec(yourUrl)`

Comment: Libraries that do this tend to use regular expressions. If you're completely new to this, it might be worth learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by utilizing looking at the `pathname` like so:

`var pathParts = window.location.pathname.split('/');`

This will give you an array containing each part of the path which you can then further parse as needed. If you are trying to do so for just a list of URLs as strings (instead of `window.location`), you can parse a string containing a URL by doing so:

```
var url = new URL("https://domain.name/resources/:id");
var pathParts = url.href.split('/'); //for example, href will have the url in string type for split
// pathParts = ['resources', ':id'];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. however; maybe what I want is a method to generate a regular expression from REST router rules : )

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Path-to-Regex

[Path to Regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)

Math function can help you

> The match function will return a function for transforming paths into parameters:

```js
    // Make sure you consistently `decode` segments.
    const fn = match("/user/:id", { decode: decodeURIComponent });
    
    fn("/user/123"); //=> { path: '/user/123', index: 0, params: { id: '123' } }
    fn("/invalid"); //=> false
    fn("/user/caf%C3%A9"); //=> { path: '/user/caf%C3%A9', index: 0, params: { id: 'café' } }
```

2. You can use **URL Pattern API** (**Experimental**)

[URL Pattern API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_Pattern_API)

It can help your requirement, such as:

- Literal strings which will be matched exactly.
- Wildcards (/posts/*) that match any character.
- Named groups (/books/:id) which extract a part of the matched URL. Non-capturing groups (/books{/old}?) which make parts of a pattern optional or be matched multiple times.
- RegExp groups (/books/(\d+)) which make arbitrarily complex regex matches with a few limitations.

Hope this help.

Comment: thank you for replying but what I want is vanilla JS without any extra library